# binarySearch in Java, Mastermind Game

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Right now for a Java course I'm trying to build a Mastermind-like game. In this game a 4-digit random number is generated, and the user tries to guess the number. With each guess the computer states how many correct digits are in the right order, and how many correct digits are in the wrong order.

For some reason, everything works up to my binary search for this program, which is really the heart of the program. I've spent hours tweaking it and I still cant get it. Any ideas?

In this example I'm trying to guess 9935, I realize that's not a random number though.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: When I run this program and use the guess "9875", it does not give me the right results.

The guesses and results I'm required to find are:

> Please enter a four-digit number: 9874
>
> The number of correct digits but in the wrong place: 0
>
> The number of correct digits in the right place: 1
>
> Please enter a four-digit number: 9899
>
> The number of correct digits but in the wrong place: 1
>
> The number of correct digits in the right place: 1
>
> Please enter a four-digit number: 9593
>
> The number of correct digits but in the wrong place: 3
>
> The number of correct digits in the right place: 1
>
> Please enter a four-digit number: 9935
>
> The number of correct digits but in the wrong place: 0
>
> The number of correct digits in the right place: 4
>
> You are correct!

```
public class Mastermind {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int randomNumber = 9935;

    int[] randomArray = new int[4];

    int temp = randomNumber;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
        int n = temp%10;
        randomArray[i] = n;
        temp /= 10;
    }

    boolean found = false;

    while (found == false){

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(randomArray));
        int[] guessArray = new int[4];
        System.out.print("Please enter a four-digit number: ");
        int guessTemp = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
            int n = guessTemp%10;
            guessArray[i] = n;
            guessTemp /= 10;
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(randomArray, guessArray)){
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
            found = true;
        } else {

            int numberRightRight = 0;
            int numberRightWrong = 0;
            int indexFound = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < guessArray.length; i ++){
                System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
                indexFound = Arrays.binarySearch(guessArray, randomArray[i]);
                System.out.println(indexFound);
                if (indexFound >= 0){
                    if(indexFound == i){
                        numberRightRight++;
                    } else {
                        numberRightWrong++;
                    }
                }
            }
           System.out.println("The number of correct digits but in the wrong place: " + numberRightWrong);
           System.out.println("The number of correct digits in the right place: " + numberRightRight);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem?

Comment: My first guess is that the master array is not sorted

Comment: I ran it and it works fine for that number. Please be more specific about the problem you're having

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg- Please check edits.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - It's not supposed to be sorted, it's supposed to be a randomly produced 4-digit integer. Which is why I'm looking for the `indexOf`.

Comment: @KeyferMathewson look at the javadocs of `Arrays.binarySearch`...the input HAS to be sorted in order to make sense

Comment: @KeyferMathewson You clearly don't understand how binary searches are suppose to work.  A binary search works on divide an conquer approach on a **sorted** series of data, that way the algorithm knows in which direction it needs to move. You may like to have a quick read through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not required to use `Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)` you could use your own simple lookup method for an unsorted Array:

```
public static int findInArray(int[] array, int value) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == value) {
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

now instead of calling `Arrays.binarySearch(guessArray, randomArray[i]);` just call `findInArray(guessArray, randomArray[i])`

Comment: This is working so much better. Why is that? Isn't `binarySearch` supposed to be the best way to do this? Also, the only problem I'm seeing with this is in the first search, using `9874` as my `guessArray`. I'm supposed to get `0 wrong, 1 right`, but i'm instead getting `1 wrong, 1 right`. Any ideas?

Comment: Or just use a structure that already supports an `indexOf` operation: either `List<Integer>` or a String.  Actually, String makes a lot of sense here, since the numbers are just tokens, not numeric in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @KeyferMathewson: there are multiple comments explaining why you're using `binarySearch` incorrectly.

Comment: @Dimitri, you're right, but i wanted to change his program as little as possible

Comment: @Dmitri As this is an introductory class, we haven't actually learned `List<Integer>`, so I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @KeyferMathewson the problem with 9874 is that the 9 is in the right place but also in the wrong place since the second digit you're looking for is also a 9

Comment: @JonasAdler Is there a way to fix this without using the `List<Integer>` function? or no?

Comment: @KeyferMathewson search in the randomArray instead of the guessArray: `indexFound = findInArray(randomArray, guessArray[i]);`. The result you're supposed to find for 9899 seems strange since there are clearly two 9s in the wrong place

Comment: @JonasAdler Exactly what I'm thinking. And I did the change you're talking about, before you mentioned it, and it caused the problem you mentioned. Could be a mistake on the assignment sheet. Thank you so much for your help though.